# how to check if brand names displayed in table are in specific order

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

There is a web table which displays `product id's` and `brand Names` in two different columns.
There is a requirement to display specific brand on top, some other brand following that and some other brand after that.

Now I need to test the brand names displayed in specific order i.e first `honda` is displayed on top, next `Tata` and at the end `Maruti` is displayed.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: You added the tags for 'C#' and 'selenium', but posted HTML... Are you searching for an e2e snippet? Why/how is 'honda, tata, maruti' a valid order?

Comment: I posted HTML to just to give more details on how table content looked like. I am using Selenium and c# to do the verification, hence the tags

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear for me, you could add code or screenshot to explain it better. But if you are using HTML to create the table, just add all these brands manually and you will be all set. I hope I understood your question.